# Why is "Unbefangenheit" translated to "ease"?

Tags: meaning

I am following the book *German for Reading: A Programmed Approach* and on page 207 point 39 there is an example sentence:

> ... und mit **Unbefangenheit** die Zügel der Regierung in die Hand nahmen ...

which translates to

> ... and took the reins of the government into their hands with **ease** ...

and actually the author specifically says that **Unbefangenheit = ease**.

However, when looking upon a dictionary, I can only find meanings like *impartiality*, *objectiveness*, *unbiased*, etc. There are nothing relevent to *ease*. In fact, I even found a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2668458) saying that

> "Unbefangenheit" is the German translation of the Japanese term *mushi* ... (which) is an expression of "non-ego"... The German translation ... (means) "dissolution of bias/prejudice/interest", it indicates something like "free of ego", "impartiality" or "absence of subjectivity".

Thus my question is, how is "Unbefangenheit" related to "ease"? Is it some ancient deprecated usage?

Comment: I do not know Japanese, but I doubt that "Unbefangenheit" is the unique German translation of the Japanese "mushi". According to the linked paper "mushi" seems to a complex concept. But of course "Unbefangenheit" may be a facet of "mushi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying concept of *Unbefangenheit*, so to say, is something like "uninfluenced by prior experiences and judgements".  This state can have two concrete, but different instantiations:

- The one you looked up in a dictionary and can be translated as "impartial, objective, unbiased".  In this usage, it is applied, for example, to judges.
- A rarer usage you have found: "with a fresh mind; not sticking to tradition or old rules".  A typical phrase would be *unbefangen an eine Sache herangehen*.

Now, the translation as "ease" is not really literal, but fitting in this context, as it well represents the intended "taking a fresh start at leading the government".

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing "ancient deprecated". I interpret this as side meaning from the context.

see https://www.dwds.de/wb/Unbefangenheit

So it stems from "fangen" aka trapped. Trapped in the context of a government can mean that I am carrying around all the entanglements of the past.
"Unbefangen", the opposite, I start fresh, new, don't have to pay attention to the past so much, and therefore be at ease.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Unbefangenheit* just means, that one is not under influence of *something*, but this something is implicit and hidden in the context provided. If the context suggests *something* to mean **anything**, which is simply an extreme case, *ease* can be a viable translation, but in most cases a more restricted meaning applies.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective *befangen* means *biased* and *unbefangen* is *unbiased*. So *die Unbefangenheit* is the state of not being biased.

In your example sentence however, it is meant as an euphemism. The relevant phrase everyone knows of is

> mit der Unbefangenheit eines Kindes — „unbiased as a child“ — knowing nothing

And that's why the translator had chosen *ease* as in *die Leichtigkeit, der Leichtsinn — improvidence, foolishness*.